# Json_decode doesn't work

Tags: php, json

In my database I have table named "groups" and inside this table, among the others, I have column named "permissions" with a value {"admin": 1}. Now, in my PHP code, when I use json_decode function, nothing happens, function doesn't work and it won't print anything. This is my code:

```
$group = $this->_db->get('groups', array('id', '=', $this->data()->protyp));
$permissions = json_decode($group->first()->permissions, true);
print_r($permissions);
```

When I echo $permissions = $group->first()->permissions; (without json_decode), everything works, but when I use json_decode, nothing happens. I use PHP 5.6. Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your desired output? and what is your current output without `json_decode()` in comparison?

Comment: My desired output is Array([admin] => 1), but nothing happens. When I echo without json_decode() result is {"admin: 1"}

Comment: `{"admin: 1"}` is not a valid Json.
Valid json would be : `{"admin": 1}`

Comment: Oh my God man, thanks, such a stupid mistake, and after 5 hours of torture, you saved me